Declaring an empty delegate vs Null Conditional
In my opinion, the fewer conditionals and checks I need to do, the better.
When I use C# a common pattern for me is declaring events something like this:
public event Action MyEvent = delegate { };

MyEvent.Invoke();

(don't sweat the details too much the empty delegate is the important part)
However I see others use:
public event Action MyEvent;

MyEvent?.Invoke();

And some tell me I should do that instead of the empty delegate. However in my opinion the empty delegate saves me a conditional check.
Is one better than the other or can I note this down as a preference in the grand scheme of things?

FYI

well, you save yourself one thing but you cost yourself the invocation of the empty delegate each time the event fires.

@tinmanjk You are correct, however, in terms of processing and overhead are we talking ns or ms difference?

@OmniOwl well, you can always benchmark it. But don't think you are saving yourself anything here (if you do).

@OmniOwl also the delegates that are behind the event are immutable, so each time you subscribe to the event you are copying the empty delegate anew.

@tinmanjk That's a fair point.

A null-conditional compiles down to a cmp jne instruction pair on x86/64, I'd be surprised if that took more than a few ns. Correct branch prediction means it doesn't even exist, incorrect prediction (itself not that likely here) requires clearing (part of) the pipeline, which is still pretty quick, and overall it's probably a lot quicker than a call ret which requires messing around the stack.
